# Double for loop is only giving back last item

Tags: r

I have the following list (the actual list is bigger but I made it smaller so its easier to understand:

```
clubs <- c("Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Southhampton")
```

What I would like to do is loop over the clubs and find all opponents. So in case of Southhampton:

```
[1] "Southhampton VS Arsenal"
[1] "Southhampton VS Chelsea"
[1] "Southhampton VS Southhampton
```

And I would like to do this for all clubs (so also Arsenal and Chelsea).

Therefore I wrote the following code:

```
 distances <- function(list) {

  #list for storing purposes
  list_new <- c()
  count <- length(list)

   #perform one loop for each club
   for (j in count) {

     for (i in list){

     #get the first club
     var <- list[j]

     #fetch list item
     var_opponent <- list(i)

     #print(var_opponent)
     var_total <- paste0(var, " VS ", var_opponent)

     print(var_total)

    list_new <- c(list_new, var_total)

    }

 }

}
```

It does not completely work however cause this is my output:

```
> distances(clubs)
[1] "Southhampton VS Arsenal"
[1] "Southhampton VS Chelsea"
[1] "Southhampton VS Southhampton"
```

Could anybody explain to me why I only get the records of the last club?

Comment: Maybe you should look at the `combn` function. Like `combn(clubs, 2)`.

Comment: length(list) return 3 (the number of clubs) sor your first loop is actually for j in 3. => Try `seq_along(list) instead of `lenght(list)`

Comment: it is not a good idea to name an object `list`. This may cause confusion with the function `list()`

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one error in your code.

The first thing you need to understand is that for loops in R goes through a list of elements. Lets assume that count is 3 in your code. The first for loop would then be

```
for(j in 3)
```

So j will be all elements in the list that consists of a single 3. 
In the next for loop you iterate through the list in the correct way.

```
for(i in list)
```

will assign each club in list to the variable i one at a time. Thus the club name (not the index of the clubname) is stored in the variable i and you don't need to index the list to get the club name.

The second error is to "index" the list with

```
 list(i)
```

This will not have anything to do with the list parameter passed to the function. This is a call to the list function and this will put the variable i in a list.

This is how your code should look like

```
distances <- function(clubs) {

  list_new <- c()

   #perform one loop for each club
   for (club1 in clubs) {

     for (club2 in clubs){


     var_total <- paste0(club1, " VS ", club2)

     print(var_total)

    list_new <- c(list_new, var_total)

    }

 }

}
```

And here is a better way to solve the problem

```
distances <-  function(clubs) combn(rep(clubs,2),2,function(x) paste(x[1] ,"VS", x[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct your function by just iterating over the list of clubs twice directly:

```
distances <- function(lst) {

    # list for storing purposes
    list_new <- c()
    count <- length(lst)

    # perform one loop for each club
    for (j in list) {
        for (i in list) {
            # get the first and second club
            # print(var_opponent)
            var_total <- paste0(j, " VS ", i)

            print(var_total)

            list_new <- c(list_new, var_total)
        }
    }
}

> distances(clubs)
[1] "Arsenal VS Arsenal"
[1] "Arsenal VS Chelsea"
[1] "Arsenal VS Southhampton"
[1] "Chelsea VS Arsenal"
[1] "Chelsea VS Chelsea"
[1] "Chelsea VS Southhampton"
[1] "Southhampton VS Arsenal"
[1] "Southhampton VS Chelsea"
[1] "Southhampton VS Southhampton"
```

Comment: There are no need to put i and j in lists. In the expression var1 <- list(i) list isn't the list passed to the function but the list function. This is just wrong and confusing. just use for(var1 in list) instead of for (i in list)

Comment: @nist I made the change please kindly upvote thanks.